# Proteger archivos con datos sensibles en PHP

Tags: php, seguridad

En PHP podemos usar archivos para guardar datos sensibles, pero esos archivos deben tener ciertos niveles de protección.

Vamos a tomar el ejemplo de un archivo que guarda nuestras credenciales de conexión a la base de datos.

Para guardar esa información tan importante he creado un archivo `db.php.ini` que contiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php return; ?>
; credenciales
host=localhost
usuario=elusuariodeladb
clave="laclave"
dbnombre=elnombredeladb
```

Este archivo aplica varios niveles de seguridad:

1. Está en una carpeta fuera del root o de `public_html`, por tanto no se podrá acceder a él mediante el navegador
2. Está en una carpeta oculta `.credenciales`
3. Tiene esto al principio `<?php return; ?>` para que, si por alguna casualidad se accede a él por URL no muestre nada.

La lectura de ese archivo, al momento de conectar a la base de datos, se hace así:

```
private function Connect()
    {
    /* Leer credenciales desde el  archivo ini */
        $this->credenciales = parse_ini_file(".credentials/db.php.ini");
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $this->credenciales["dbnombre"] . 
               ';host=' . $this->credenciales["host"] . '';
        $pwd = $this->credenciales["clave"];
        $usr = $this->credenciales["usuario"];
// ... más código
}
```

### La pregunta

**¿Existen otras medidas que podrían tomarse para darle más seguridad a este archivo? ¿Cuáles serían esas medidas?**

Comment: Estando fuera de la estructura accesible desde web, no veo la necesidad de esas etiquetas php, aunque, en todo caso, la extensión debería ser **.php** para que funcione, porque, al ser **.ini** (suponiendo que se pueda acceder) se mostraría el contenido como texto. La función **parse_ini_file()** puede leer cualquier archivo de texto con cualquier extensión, la única duda es si **<?php return; ?>** debería estar precedida de punto y coma o no.

Comment: @Triby el archivo funciona así como lo tengo, de hecho, lo uso así para conectar a la base de datos.

Comment: Ok, supuse que el parser podría generar un error al no tener comentada la primera línea. Pero lo de la extensión, al ser **.ini**, si fuese accesible desde web, el servidor no invocará el intérprete de PHP y, por tanto, se mostraría el contenido como texto.

Comment: No @Triby. Ya lo había probado, y lo probé ahora de nuevo. Si quito el código PHP es cuando se muestra el contenido del archivo, pero si le pongo el código PHP no muestra nada. Puedes hacer la prueba si quieres.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si ves el código fuente en el navegador?, según las pruebas que hice hace algunos ayeres, aparecía todo, pero no se mostraba en la "vista normal" porque **<?php** iniciaba un HTML mal formado, convirtiéndose en una etiqueta sin cierre.

Comment: Revisando el código fuente, tenemos esto: `<head></head><body></body>`.  No hay absolutamente ninguna información que se muestre.

Comment: Entonces cabe suponer que tienes el servidor configurado para que PHP interprete archivos con extensión **.ini** y por eso no hay problema.

Comment: @Triby no te podría decir nada a ese respecto. En realidad los archivos están en un hosting compartido, ligados a un dominio, es así como uso PHP. No me he fijado si la configuración de PHP tenga esa opción, y tampoco sabría cuál sería dicha opción.

Comment: Y cómo estás haciendo las pruebas para invocar ese .ini?, lo colocaste en public_html?

Comment: Claro @Triby, lo coloqué en `public_html` y accedí a él vía URL. El archivo se abre, no hay error 404, pero no muestra nada, ni en pantalla ni en el código fuente.

Comment: Entonces el último posible riesgo de seguridad es el "normal" de estar en un servidor compartido, pero eso ya depende solo del administrador del hosting.

Comment: Tal como explicas que lo tienes es suficiente. Tu archivo esta tan seguro como sea tu servidor. Aparte de eso lo dicho hasta ahora, una vez que estés en producción yo personalmente desactivaría el acceso al hosting por ftp o mínimo eliminar usuarios por defecto y utilizar contraseñas robustas para cualquier tipo de acceso al hosting.

Comment: @Xerif agradecería alguna respuesta, para que la pregunta no quede abierta.

Comment: Considero importante abordar también el control desde el archivo .htaccess para brindar mayor seguridad de las aplicaciones que existan dentro del server... con este archivo es posible generar directrices y evitar comportamientos inesperados de usuarios visitantes a un sitio web. Saludos.

Comment: @A. Cedano, por favor, ¿podría poner un ejemplo completo de lo que indica?
Estoy intentando seguir sus pasos pero no soy capaz. Muchas gracias. Un saludo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A la hora de trabajar con archivos sensibles (credenciales, archivos de configuracion, conexiones a base de datos) en un servidor web lo recomendable es que estén ubicados siempre fuera del directorio público, de forma que no se pueda acceder directamente a ellos.

Pero ¿es suficiente con poner los archivos en un directorio no público?

Obviamente no, debemos de tener en cuenta algunas recomendaciones para limitar el acceso de estos archivos por otros medios.

- Establecer solo los permisos necesarios.
- Evitar el uso de funciones PHP (u otros lenguajes) que puedan ejecutar código o comandos (ejmplo: eval, exec ...) y en caso de ser necesario ser muy cuidadoso.
- Evitar utilizar rutas por defecto a los paneles de administración (ejemplo: dominio.com/cpanel).
- Evitar o restringir el acceso ftp en producción y/o usuario por defecto o contraseñas débiles.

Esto no nos garantiza una seguridad 100% ya que un servidor se puede ver comprometido debido a otros factores.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias amigo. un gran aporte no lo sabía y se lo agradezco sinceramente. Pero me di cuenta que la extensión del archivo es ini cuando debería ser php, le comento, porque lo puse a prueba y mostraba los datos debido a que no resuelve la instrucción php y es obvio. De manera que revertí la extensión y así queda db.ini.php y listo. Al decir que a usted le funciona deduzco que a nivel de sistema (el parseo) pero no al visualizarlo en la url. Pero no se le de nada porque fíjate cuantos años y tu aporte aún de gran utilidad.

Saludos

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Por favor no agregues una respuesta que diga gracias. Invierte algun tiempo en el sitio y ganaras suficiente [reputación](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges) para votar a las respuestas que te gustaron. Esa es la forma de decir gracias en Stack Overflow en español.