# Problema para acceder a array multidimensional en php

Tags: php, drupal8

El problema consiste en lo siguiente:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'mibasededatos',
  'username' => 'miusuario',
  'password' => '1234',
  'prefix' => 'test_',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

Dado este array multidimensional de necesito sacar los valores de database, username, password y prefix.

Como algunos se habrán dado cuenta, esto es la conexión a la base de datos de un Drupal 8. Hay métodos facilitados por Drupal para sacarlo, pero no puedo/quiero usarlos, pues estoy generando un archivo independiente que va a trabajar a la par que un módulo custom. El caso es que, ya que tengo esos datos ahí, no quiero pedírselos al admin de nuevo, me parece innecesario marear al admin, y quería recogerlos de aquí. Esto se encuentra en un archivo llamado settings.php y puedo acceder perfectamente a el.

He llegado a hacer el include del archivo, pero no soy capaz de sacar los valores. Probé un `foreach` probé `array_map()`, `array_key` y `array_value()` pero solo me devuelve default o me devuelve todo el array sin poder seleccionar los valores.

No necesito el key, solo el value.

¿Una ayudita?.

Comment: Los datos los encuentras así: `$db=$databases['default']['default']['database'];  $usr=$databases['default']['default']['username'];`, etc. Ahí tendrías en las variables `$db` y `$usr` el nombre de la base de datos y el del usuario. Aunque, tratándose de las credenciales de la BD yo crearía mi propio archivo `.ini` guardándolo en una carpeta oculta, fuera del root (algo parecido a lo planteado en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/115290/29967)). No es bueno poner las credenciales en un script directamente.

Comment: Buenas. Dos cosas: 1º Efectivamente, en un .ini las tenia, pero no lo veo práctico, porque requiero primero de poder llegar a las claves, en el archivo este, para poder copiarlas y mandarlas al .ini. El archivo settings está en una zona de solo lectura por el usuario apache, del servidor y no se puede llegar desde fuera, lanza un 403 cuando intentas leerlo. 2º Muchas gracias, de tres preguntas que he hecho, dos me las has solucionado tu. A este paso me va a tocar pagarte unas cervecillas, o vino, lo que mas te mole. Ponlo como respuesta y la pongo por válida, así queda ahí por si acaso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el array que muestras, puedes encontrar los datos así:

```
$db=$databases['default']['default']['database']; 
$usr=$databases['default']['default']['username'];
$pwd=$databases['default']['default']['password'];
```

Ahí tendrías en cada variable los valores que requieres, y podrás usarlas de una forma clara en el código.

**NOTA:**

En un contexto en el que las credenciales dependan de ti (que el hosting no las cambie *ad libitum*  sin tu permiso), es mucho más seguro colocar las claves en un **archivo php tipo ini** por llamarle de alguna forma porque es realmente un archivo PHP además con extensión `ini` donde guardarías las claves en un sitio fuera del root, preferiblemente en una carpeta oculta, pudiendo leer los datos desde cualquier script. Ver la pregunta [Proteger archivos con datos sensibles en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/115290/29967) para más detalles sobre esto.