# Proteger password en phpmailer

Tags: php, html5, gmail

Estoy creando un formulario de contacto en un servidor vps con phpmailer. Utilizo el correo de gmail y su password de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

$config = parse_ini_file('/var/app/config.ini', true);

// PHPMailer
$mail->Username = $config['email']['username'];
$mail->Password = $config['email']['password'];
```

Es una forma segura de proteger la contraseña y el correo? aún es posible de ver la contraseña?

Comment: Hola, si estas enviando la contraseña sin encriptar obviamente no esta segura, mejor usa un algoritmo de encriptación como SHA1 o al menos un md5. Saludos.

Comment: Si no estan en directorio publico, su seguridad va a depender de la seguridad de tu servidor y del correcto uso de funciones que puedan ejecutar codigo arbitrario por ejemplo `eval`, puedes revisar esta respuesta que viene a decir mas menos lo mismo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115290/proteger-archivos-con-datos-sensibles-en-php/119643#119643

Comment: Correcto Xerif mí archivo config.ini está fuera de la carpeta pública, con dos variables username: nombreUsuario y password: Contraseña Con eso sería suficiente? o es conveniente hacer algo más?