# cómo ocultar credenciales en una conexión PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Muy buenas,

Tengo una conexión PDO a SQL SERVER en la cual le doy en duro las credenciales de mi base de datos.

Al momento de poner una credencial erronea, me arroja un error de PDO y me muestra tal cual la información de mis credenciales.

Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de que, al existir un error en las credenciales, estas no se mostraran al usuario y quedaran ocultas.

He probado algunas formas para que no me muestre la informacion de mis credenciales usando `try` y `catch` y dando un error a mi antojo, y otras ocultando los errores de PHP...

De todas formas me surge la duda de como ocultar esta información.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

COD:

```
class Database{

    // CONEXION A SQL SERVER CON PDO
    public static function connect(){
         $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=IP;Database=DBNAME", "USER", "PASS");
         $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
         $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         return $db;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Prueba encerrar tu código de conexión en un bloque try...catch y lanza un error personalizado y no el error original

Comment: gracias @Francisco, apliqué esto definitivamente en mi proyecto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes gestionar la conexión dentro de un bloque `try ... catch` y en el `catch` escribes un error personalizado en el log de errores.

Por ejemplo:

```
class Database{

// CONEXION A SQL SERVER CON PDO
    public static function connect(){
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        try {
             $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=IP;Database=DBNAME;charset=utf8", "USER", "PASS",$options);
             return $db;  
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log("Error en la conexión");
            return NULL;
        }        
}
```

Aquí he introducido algunas mejoras de seguridad:

1. He apagado las preparaciones emuladas, pues vienen `TRUE` por defecto y alguna inyección de código es posible cuando están encendidas.
2. He pasado el charset en el DSN, es mucho mejor, porque luego no tienes que modificar la conexión.
3. He pasado las configuraciones como un cuarto parámetro en forma de array, es totalmente válido y más práctico por lo mismo dicho en (2). El objeto se crea ya configurado de una vez.

Como consejo adicional de seguridad, usa contraseñas largas y difíciles. Si alguna vez se colase la contraseña en un log de errores, al ser larga quedará truncada en algún punto y no se verá completa.

Como seguridad adicional para tus credenciales puedes consultar también esta pregunta: [Proteger archivos con datos sensibles en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/115290/29967)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, aplicaré tus consejos de seguridad a mi conexion :D