# Como hacer referencia a la cadena de conexion de wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

quiero realizar una referencia a la cadena de conexion de wordpress, ya que he estado haciendo cadenas de conexion propias, pero no deseo hacerla de esa forma, ya que quiero que sea mas transparente.

esta es mi cadena de conexion:

```
 $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "mydb";
    $username = "myuser";
    $password = "mypass";

    // Create connection

    $conn = New PDO("mysql: host=$servername; dbname=$database;","$username","$password");
```

como puedo resolver mi inconveniente?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con `conexión propia` y `más transparente`? Ese es el formato que se debe usar en PHP para conectar a base de datos; quizá lo único que puedes hacer es remplazar las variables por sus valores, pero no le veo sentido.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando usas wordpress tienen una cadena de conexion en el wp-config.php y no se como hacer referencia a el, como otro punto, estoy utilizando un tema y pues este archivo se encuentra en la carpeta raiz y no se como hacer referencia.

Comment: Si lo que necesitas es acceder a la clase que maneja base de datos, usa `$wpdb`; más información en: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Como bien dices, las credenciales para la conexión están en `wp-config.php` una posibilidad sería incluir ese archivo en el contexto donde quieres usar las credenciales de conexión, aunque **yo no haría eso** por algo muy simple, no tiene sentido incluir un archivo entero tan solo para usar cuatro variables. Yo **guardaría las credenciales en un archivo de configuración oculto**. Así estarían seguras, no serían accesibles a nadie y podrías usarlas para tu conexión a PDO. [Aquí se abordó un problema parecido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/115290/29967) que podría serte de ayuda.