# PHP: clase con método estático de conexión MySQLi pero que permita variar los parámetros de conexión si es necesario

Tags: php, mysqli, poo, static

Estoy empezando con PHP OO y lo primero que he intentado crear es una clase para gestionar la conexión a mi base de datos vía MySQLi.

Lo he hecho mediante un método estático, para poder incluirlo en mis modelos sin necesidad de instanciar:

```
class MySQL
{
    static function conectar()
    {
        $servidor = "localhost"; 
        $usuario = "root"; 
        $contrasena = ""; 
        $base_datos = "recopilatorios";

        $mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $contrasena, $base_datos);
        $conexion = $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

        return $conexion;
    }
}
```

También he pensado que en determinadas circunstancias podría ser necesario alterar los parámetros de conexión, por ejemplo para conectarse a otra base de datos, y en ese caso sí sería necesario instanciar un objeto e indicarle los cambios a través de un método constructor... ¿le veis sentido?

He intentado modificar la clase para afrontar esa eventualidad:

```
class MySQL
{
    private $servidor = "localhost"; 
    private $usuario = "root"; 
    private $contrasena = ""; 
    private $base_datos = "recopilatorios";

    private static $conexion;

    function __construct($servidor, $usuario, $contrasena, $base_datos)
    {
        $this->servidor = $servidor;
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
        $this->contrasena = $contrasena;
        $this->base_datos = $base_datos;
    }

    private function instanciar()
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->contrasena, $this->base_datos);
        $mysqli = $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

        return $mysqli;
    }

    static function conectar()
    {
        self::$conexion = instanciar();

        return self::$conexion;
    }
}
```

Ésta ha sido una de varias versiones, y todas fallan; en este caso concreto, al intentar la conexión de la siguiente manera:

```
$mysql = new MySQL("localhost", "root", "", "mundo");
$mysql::conectar();
```

Me da el siguiente error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function instanciar()`

¿Cómo resolveríais vosotros el problema -si acaso tiene sentido resolverlo-?

**EDICIÓN**:

Siguiendo vuestras recomendaciones he rehecho mi clase de la siguiente manera y parece que funciona:

```
class MySQL
{
    private static $servidor = "localhost"; 
    private static $usuario = "root"; 
    private static $contrasena = ""; 
    private static $base_datos = "recopilatorios";

    private static $conexion;

    function __construct($base_datos) {self::$base_datos = $base_datos;}

    private static function instanciar()
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(self::$servidor, self::$usuario, self::$contrasena, self::$base_datos);
        $mysqli_utf8 = $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

        return $mysqli_utf8;
    }

    static function conectar()
    {
        self::$conexion = self::instanciar();

        return self::$conexion;
    }
}
```

Si intento la conexión a otra base de datos:

```
$mysql = new MySQL("world");
var_dump($mysql);
$conexion = $mysql::conectar();
var_dump($conexion);

C:\wamp64\www\Recopilatorios\PHP\Web\MVC\index.php:7:
object(MySQL)[1]
C:\wamp64\www\Recopilatorios\PHP\Web\MVC\index.php:9:boolean true
```

Comment: *¿Le veis sentido?*, preguntas. Yo diría que **NO**, por algo muy simple: las credenciales de conexión no deberían estar viajando por ahí en forma de parámetros, como si fueran datos cualesquiera. Si vas a trabajar con BD distintas, a lo sumo podrías pasar en parámetro el nombre de la BD, pero tener en archivos bien asegurados las credenciales, así, según la BD que sea, decides qué archivo usar. Sugiero que [leas aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/115290/29967), con las credenciales en archivos protegidos ganas en seguridad y en simplicidad.

Comment: Sí, realmente la única característica que me interesaría cambiar sería el nombre de la base de datos; quizá se podría restringir el método constructor a ese único parámetro.

Comment: lo que necesitarías sería pasar esas variables de instancia a variables privadas o protegidas estáticas, igual que tu conexión, entonces en lugar de `$this->variable = $tal;`, guardarías esos datos como `self::$host = $host;`

Answer (score 1):

1. Para llamar metodo de instancia de clase debes utilizar `$this`:

```
$conexion = $this->instanciar();
```

2. Pero no es possible utilizar `$this` dentro de static function porque en funciónes estáticas no hay instancias. Elimina `static` y llama este metodo como

```
$mysql->conectar();
```

Comment: Pero necesito que el método sea estático para poder llamarlo sin tener que instanciar un objeto. En la mayoría de las ocasiones no habría necesidad de instanciar porque usaría los parámetros por defecto.

Comment: @Optigan en este caso necesitas hacer todas las variables y metodos estáticas. Por supuesto, `__construct` no puede set estático, necesitas nombrarlo como `set_credentials` por exemplo. Todo esto resultará en implementación del patrón OOP muy común: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton